# Discarded records of .csv file by solr

Tags: csv, solr

solr - solr-8.9.0, java version "11.0.12" 2021-07-20 LTS

Loaded a .csv file in solr using following command.

```
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/testColl/update?commit=true" --data-binary @$csvFileName -H 'Content-type:application/csv'
```

Total number of records loaded in solr was less than the number of records in .csv file.

How can i know which records of csv-file were discarded by solr?
I understand that to count number of loaded records following is command.

```
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/testColl/query?q=*:*&rows=0"
```

How can i generate discarded log files(of records in .csv file which was failed to load in solr.)?

Comment: Usually this is caused by duplicate entries in the field you use as the unique key field in your schema; try to manually check the number of unique values (if the csv-file is small enough to be opened as a spreadsheet you can make the spreadsheet count the unique values), or you can use `cut`, `sort` and `uniq` to find the number of uniq entries in your first column for example (if that's the one you're using as your unique id column)

Comment: @MatsLindh, Thankx for reply! While defining managed-schema i have not defined any unique key field.  There are 500 milion rows in .csv file. There are 4 column in .csv file and one of the field is defined as 'plong' in managed-schema. There are string values in .csv file for this field. How can i generate discarded log files of rows which are failed to load?

Comment: I am looking for something like sqlldr command of oracle which create bad file, log fie, error-file etc. In Solr can i generate log file of discarded records?

Comment: I am a loading .csv file in solr, if any error occurs while loading, than some records are inserted and some records are yet to insert. How can i sync my solr instance? I want to delete all records which are inserted,so than i can give trigger to same file again.